# How to add or multiple the values of a chechkbox

Tags: php

I am trying to sum up the values of checkbox value using a foreach loop... but i am confused as to where to add the signs so the values can add up.

Where do i include the addition sign so it can sum up whatever number value so i can get the total?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $main_odds      = $_POST["total_odds"];
    if(!empty($main_odds)){
        echo "You have selected the following games ";
        foreach ($main_odds as $final_odd){
            echo "<td>$final_odd</td>" ;
        }
    }else{
        echo "You have not selected any odds";
    }

}
$total_odds = "";
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>calculate</th>
        <th>odds</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php foreach($games as $game): ?>
      <tr> 
       <td><?= $game->odds; ?></td>
        <td>
        <form method="Post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="total_odds[]"  value="<?= $game->odds; ?>">
        </td>
      </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
         <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
         </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your html markup is invalid.

Comment: @u_mulder my code displays what ever i select from my checkbox irrespective of how many selections i check... thats why it is a loop

Comment: You dont need forloop just use array_sum `array_sum($main_odds);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all values within the loop.

```
echo "You have selected the following games: ";
$total = 0;
foreach ($main_odds as $final_odd){
    $total += $final_odd;
    echo "<td>$final_odd</td>" ;
}
echo "<br>Total value is " . $total;
```

Comment: Thanks... What about how to multiply the values?

Comment: ```
$total += $final_odd;  // this is shortf cut for $total = $total + $final_odd;

// Multiplication
$total = $total * $final_odd;     // and so on
```

Comment: i am getting zero as my answer... can you please show me in code?

Comment: Please post your new code, so that I can help you debug it.

Comment: Please check the answer below my answer.

Comment: Ahh, got the issue. You have to define your form before the foreach loop i.e., just before the </tbody> tag. Since your <form> tag is inside the loop it will print itself recursively and will only show your results if you select the last checkbox.

It's always recommended to place your opening and closing <form> tags as the parent tag of your container. Here, you should place your start <form> tag before the <table> tag and the closing <form> tag after </table> tag. Hope it helps.

Ps: A <form> tag inside another <form> tag does not work.

Comment: i am getting same same results

Comment: Share a screenshot of your User Interface (page).

Comment: i already got my answer... since a loop counts after the completion of each calculation, i changed the zero variable to 1 so it multiplies each calculation by 1 and that solved it. and thanks for trying to help out

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$main_oddddd = "";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $main_odds      = $_POST["total_odds"];

    if(!empty($main_odds)){
        $val = 0;
        echo "You have selected the following games ";
        foreach ($main_odds as $final_odd){
             $val += $final_odd;
        }
    }else{
        echo "You have not selected any odds";
    }
    $main_oddddd = count($main_odds);
    echo $val;
}

?>

<?php 
$main_oddddd = "";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $main_odds      = $_POST["total_odds"];
    //echo $main_value     = implode(", ",  $main_odds);
    $total = 0;
    if(!empty($main_odds)){

        echo "You have selected the following games ";
        foreach ($main_odds as $final_odd){
            $total = $total * $final_odd;
        }
    }else{
        echo "You have not selected any odds";
    }
    $main_oddddd = count($main_odds);
    echo $total;
}

?>
```